# My 'about me' on my profile has been hacked. What's the procedure?

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, profile-page

Title states it all. The blurb in the 'about me' is not from me. I have no idea who gained access and placed this stuff there.

I'm leaving it there for now. Besides determining, perhaps, who may have done this, I think the rest of us should know the procedure if this occurs.

Thanks for your time and help.

Below is a screenshot.

[image: DanF's profile page, in edit mode]

The "About me" section contains the following strange text:

> BY DAY: Alt-Rock Ninja Cowgirl at Veridian Dynamics.
>   BY NIGHT: I write code and code rights for penalcoders.example.org, an awesome non-profit that will totally take your money at that link.
>   My kids are cuter than yours.
>   FOR FUN: C+ Jokes, Segway Roller Derby, NYT Sat. Crosswords (in Sharpie!), Ostrich Grooming.
>   "If you see scary things, look for the helpers-you'll always see people helping."-Fred Rogers

Comment: What are you seeing, and what were you expecting to see?

Comment: FYI potential identifying information in the other tab.

Answer (score 7):

That's default text that is visible if you haven't set any "about me" — but only to you and only on the page that allows you set that field. If you start typing in that box, that text should disappear. If it doesn't, please report a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: Got it. It is weird, I must say. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @DanF: The behavior is probably inherited from Stack Overflow. The text you quoted is only truly funny if you're a computer programmer.

Comment: @DanF: If you want the behavior to be changed, simply file a feature request on the Meta Stack Exchange website.

Comment: I was gonna say he sounds like a pretty cool person imo